# Implement "For loop" on prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog

How to Implement using recursion and cut-off cycle of the counter 
(like `for i: = 1 downto N do <operator>`) ?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want do do.

Comment: If you're implementing loops in Prolog, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: for example, how implements this code on strawberry prolog
for i:=1 to N do begin
i:=i+1;
end;

Comment: @Patrick87 why it is wrong to loop in prolog?

Answer (score 10):

my naive implementation, to be seen as an extendend between/3

```
:- module(loop, [upto/4, downto/4]).

upto(Low,High,_Step,Low) :- Low =< High.
upto(Low,High,Step,Var) :-
    Inc is Low+Step,
    Inc =< High,
    upto(Inc, High, Step, Var).

downto(Low,High,_Step,High) :- Low =< High.
downto(Low,High,Step,Var) :-
    Dec is High-Step,
    Dec >= Low,
    downto(Low, Dec, Step, Var).
```

usage:

```
8 ?- forall(upto(0,6,3,V),writeln(V)).
0
3
6
true.

9 ?- forall(downto(0,6,3,V),writeln(V)).
6
3
0
true.
```

another example, the easiest question posed @ this year [Prolog programming contest](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.demoen/PrologProgrammingContests/2013/probs2013.pdf):

```
icecream(N) :-
    loop(N, top(N)),
    left, loop(N+1, center), nl,
    loop(N+1, bottom(N)).

:- meta_predicate loop(+, 1).

loop(XH, PR) :-
    H is XH,
    forall(between(1, H, I), call(PR, I)).

top(N, I) :-
    left, spc(N-I+1), pop,
    (   I > 1
    ->  pop,
        spc(2*(I-2)),
        pcl
    ;   true
    ),
    pcl, nl.

bottom(N, I) :-
    left, spc(I-1), put(\), spc(2*(N-I+1)), put(/), nl.

center(_) :- put(/), put(\).

left :- spc(4).
pop :- put(0'().
pcl :- put(0')).
spc(Ex) :- V is Ex, forall(between(1, V, _), put(0' )).
```

yields

```
?- icecream(4).
        ()
       (())
      ((  ))
     ((    ))
    /\/\/\/\/\
    \        /
     \      /
      \    /
       \  /
        \/
true.
```

note: loop in the second snippet is unrelated to first...

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that you don't.

Prolog is a declaritive language, not a procedural language. It comes from the predicate calculus. You describe the problem space in terms of facts and rules (the "database"). This forms a collection of connected, directed graphs.

You formulate an initial goal that describes the solution to your "problem" and let the inference engine find the solution(s), if any.

The inference engine starts with the initial goal you give it. It evaluates it in terms of the database, walking the graph as it goes, backtracking on failure, until it finds a solution (or not). Backtracking into the initial goal will cause it to look for the next solution, if any.

So the notion of a procedural construct such as a loop is rather non-idiomatic (to say the  least) and (in my experience, at least) is pretty much a guarantee of poor performance.

Answer (score 4):

Nicholas Carey is correct in advising you to think declaratively rather than procedurally for Prolog. However I take the question to mean something like, "How can I use Prolog to solve a certain kind of task for which I would employ loops in other languages: in particular, how can I get some set of results or outcomes?" For there are certainly times when, working completely within a declarative idiom, we want to describe N of something.  The main difference will be that in instead of having to fit every problem into a loop, there are different ways of solving these kinds of problems depending on the nature of the problem itself.

twinterer's answer works, but is confined to an imperative idiom within a particular language.

Here are possible solutions for three common cases written in common, declarative Prolog idioms:

For numbers from N to M, you can use the built in predicate `between(N,M,Num)`:

```
?- between(1, 5, X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.
```

For a list containing N instances of X, we can use a predicate like this:

```
n_xs(N, X, Xs) :-
    length(Xs, N),          % Creates a list of N uninstantiated variables.
    maplist('='(X), Xs).    % Unifies each variable with X
```

Then, to get your list:

```
?- n_xs(5, dingo, Ds).
Ds = [dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo].
```

This predicate can also be used to verify the length of a list which already contains a single homogeneous element,

```
?- n_xs(5, dingo, [dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo]).
true.

?- n_xs(N, dingo, [dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo, dingo]).
N = 5.
```

For performing some action N times, we can use something like this:

```
x_written_n_times(X, N) :-
    foreach(between(1,N,_), write(X)).

?- x_written_n_times('dingo\n', 5).
dingo
dingo
dingo
dingo
dingo
true.
```

More information on kinds of looping behavior can be found at the bottom of this tutorial: http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/student/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The ECLiPSe language (which basically is a variant of Prolog) has a `do/2` predicate which is used to build loops. Using loops in Prolog code is sometimes useful, since it leads to more readable code that is also easier to change.

However, the `do/2` predicate is in effect just a macro that gets translated into a recursive predicate, so that underneath it's still recursive:

```
?- ( for(I,From,To,Inc) do Body ).
```

maps into something like

```
?- do__1(From, To, Inc).
do__1(I, To, Inc) :- Inc >= 0, I > To, !.
do__1(I, To, Inc) :- Inc  < 0, I < To, !.
do__1(I, To, Inc) :- Body, Next is I+Inc, do__1(Next, To, Inc).
```

(see the paper [Logical Loops](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0E97335D5AD4C15DE3BB9040DA9006FC?doi=10.1.1.6.9498&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which also gives a number of reasons why logical loops are preferable to pure recursion)

Answer (score 2):

I have written an [interpreter for imperative functions](https://github.com/jarble/imperative_prolog) in Prolog. This is an example of its usage:

```
:- initialization(main).

main :-
    imperative(Result,[
        a = 1,
        b = 2,
        z = b + 1,
        while(a < 10,[
            a = a + 1,
            (a mod 3 = 0) ->
                [writeln(a mod 2),
                writeln(a)]
        ])
    ]),
    writeln(Result).
```

and this is its implementation:

```
while(List,Result,Condition,Statements) :-
    get_var(List,Condition_,Condition),
    (Condition_ -> (imperative(List,Result_,Statements),while(Result_,Result,Condition,Statements));
    List=Result).

imperative_(List,Result,Command) :-
    (member(A:_,List),
    replaceP(A:A1,A:A2,List,Result);Result=[A:A2|List]),
    (Command = increment(A,B), A2 is A1 + B;
    Command = increment(A), A2 is A1 + 1;
    Command = decrement(A), A2 is A1 - 1;
    Command = (A = B), get_var(List,A2,B)).

imperative_(List,Result,while(Condition,Statements)) :-
    while(List,Result,Condition,Statements).

imperative_(List,List,writeln(A)) :-
    get_var(List,A_,A),
    writeln(A_).

imperative_(List,Result,(Condition -> Statements)) :-
    get_var(List,Condition_,Condition),
    (Condition_ -> imperative(List,Result,Statements);List=Result).

imperative(Result,Steps) :- imperative([],Result,Steps).

imperative(List,Result,[Step]) :-
    imperative_(List,Result,Step).

imperative(List,Result,[Step|Rest]) :-
    imperative_(List,List1,Step), imperative(List1,Result,Rest).

get_var(List,A2,B) :- phrase(get_var(List,B),[A2]).

get_var(List,get_var(A)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A)},[A_].

get_var(List,B) -->
    {member(B:A2,List)},[A2].

get_var(_,B) -->
    {number(B)},[B].

get_var(List,(A+B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B), A2 is A_ + B_},[A2].

get_var(List,(A-B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B), A2 is A_ - B_},[A2].

get_var(List,(A/B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B), A2 is A_ / B_},[A2].

get_var(List,(A*B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B), A2 is A_ * B_},[A2].

get_var(List,(A mod B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B), A2 is A_ mod B_},[A2].

get_var(List,(A>B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B)},[A_ > B_].

get_var(List,(A<B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B)},[A_ < B_].

get_var(List,(A,B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B)},[(A_,B_)].

get_var(List,(A=B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B)},[(A_=B_)].

get_var(List,(A;B)) -->
    {get_var(List,A_,A), get_var(List,B_,B)},[(A_;B_)].

get_var(_,true) -->
    [true].

get_var(_,false) -->
    [false].

% code by @svick, modified to use dif/2 instead of (\=)/2
replaceP(_, _, [], []).
replaceP(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
replaceP(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- dif(H,O), replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
```

Comment: Nice! And it could be made **reversible** if you use *constraints* instead of moded arithmetic. For an example, check out [**revcomp**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/adrian/revcomp) by Adrian Prantl.

Answer (score 1):

A simple code snippet :

```
loop(M,N):-
   between(M, N, X),
   writeln(X),
   X >= N, !.
   loop(M,X).

Goal :
?- loop(5,10).
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've made this simple program that implements a loop in Prolog:

```
:- initialization(main).

loop(I, End) :-
  I > End;
  writeln(I), Ii is I + 1, loop(Ii, End).

main :- loop(0, 10).
```

It basically prints numbers from 0 to 10 (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i did it(using recursion) :

```
for(X , Y , Z):-
    X<Y,
    X1 is X+Z,
    writeln("Hello"),
    for(X1 , Y , Z).

nestedFor(X , Y , Z):-
    X<Y,
    X1 is X+Z,
    not(for(0 , 10 , 1)),
    writeln("World!"), 
    nestedFor(X1 , Y , Z).
```

Keep adding more functions to create more loops.