# How to do an iteration by 3

Tags: prolog

I want to do a program that goes from 1 to 9 but iterating by 3 like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i+=3);
```

I only know:

```
between(1,9,K),Z is K+3,between(K,Z,P)
```

But this doesn't works.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not enough?"

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7893939