# prolog - how to simulate a for-loop

Tags: prolog

I am trying to generate a list such as

`[X1/1,X2/2,X3/3....Xn/N] with given N.`

I tried to make a function `maketemplate(N,L)` that takes `N` and returns the list of `L` with items of `Xn/N` where `Xn` is a N-th variable, and `N` is an integer.

As a simpler example, I initially tried to make a list of `[1,2,3...N]` with given `N`, but I can't even get that to work.

```
mysolution(L,N,N).
mysolution([I|Rest],I,N):-
   I < N,
   I is I+1,
   mysolution(Rest,I+1,N).
```

How do I simulate a for-loop like operation in prolog?

Comment: The short answer is to simply forget about for-loops; in Prolog, you do things differently, yielding *more general* programs. There is a great posting by Stefan Kral about this topic in a [**previous discussion**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.prolog/VQcXWdgCraI/W_dgxafjXnIJ). A general solution lets you reason about *partially* instantiated solutions, it lets you *test* solutions etc. None of this is (efficiently) possible when thinking in only one direction of use.

Comment: There are a couple of basic, fundamental points in Prolog your program violates: (1) You can't re-instantiate a variable within a predicate clause once it's already instantiated, so `I is I+1` fails (and it fails on the basis that `I` and `I+1` cannot ever be the same value), and (2) `mysolution(Rest, I+1, N)` does *not* evaluate `I+1` as in other languages. `I+1` is just a term and will not be evaluated as an expression unless you use a Prolog operator or pedicate that evaluates it (*e.g.*, `is/2`, `=:=/2`, etc). You would need `I1 is I+1, mysolution(Rest,I1,N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking the imperative way. Failure-loops are the way to go in Prolog:

```
seq(From,_,From).
seq(From,To,X) :-
    From<To,
    Next is From+1,
    seq(Next,To,X).

loop :-
    seq(1,10,Index),
    do_something(Index),
    fail.
loop.

do_something(Index) :-
    display(Index),nl.
```

A failure-loop has the following asbtract structure:

```
loop:-
  generate(X),
  do_something(X),
  fail.
loop.
```

Comment: This answer is more than a bit misleading. Failure-driven loops **are** as imperative as Prolog gets... how about a more relational approach?

Comment: @repeat Of course, there are also [several other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893939/implement-for-loop-on-prolog) to implement imperative loops in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

A similar example I just did for creating a list contain random elements with certain count may meet your needs about get dynamic value from inner-recursion and use it out of recursion (corrected as what comment said):

```
create_list(0,X):- !, X=[].
create_list(_size,X):-
  _size>0,
  _last_size is _size-1,
  create_list(_last_size,Y),
  random(0,9,_random),
  X=[_random|Y].
```

And there are some experience:

1. You can not change variable bound with certain value, so you can not change a variable base on itself, way to get dynamic in a procedure with a limited parameter (or call it limited recursion structure may more precise) is that use recursion to create infinity, infinity can accommodate random number. Concretely, use a new variable to call your rule itself in the rule definition, like `Y` and `X` in my code. place where different variable exist should be the same, change the value after recursion, do *Unification* over and over to get inner-value.
2. Define ending condition by another rule or fact, like stop in infinity but not do a loop.
3. Sure your loop process can be reversed and can get solution after reversing ,this is a characteristic on algorithm, because usually loop is the reversion of recursion, and we can only use recursion.

I use prolog to do research more often ,if you take more interest in project development, do not think about loop may be a better choice.

Comment: `create_list(0,X):-X=[],!.` is the same as `create_list(0,[]):- !.`I assume you meant instead `create_list(0,X) :- !, X=[].`? Output unifications should occur after, not before a cut to keep the predicate *steadfast*. Also, `append([_random],Y,X)` is the same as `X = [_random| Y]`.

Comment: Yes, they are some error in my code, sorry about putting them up without careful checkup, and thanks for pointing out.